# Why does my linker search for Coin4sd.lib after it found Coin4d.lib?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, qmake, coin3d

I am using the Coin 4.0.0 library (https://github.com/coin3d/coin) for a certain project.  When building that library using CMake, I get amongst others the following files:

```
bin
|-- Coin4d.dll
`-- Coin4d.pdb
lib
|-- Coin4d.lib
```

Which looks fine to me.  Then, we are using `qmake` to build our final executable. In my qmake `.pro` file I have

```
LIBS += -lCoin4d
```

However, when the final `.exe` is linked together using the Visual Studio 2015 linker, then I see that it first searches for (and finds) `Coin4d.lib`:

```
Searching D:/SVN/simcad/trunkd/ThirdParty/Coin/install/lib\Coin4d.lib:
```

However, a bit later, I get the linker error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Coin4sd.lib'
```

Mind the extra 's' in the library file name here!

I have no idea why the linker is also looking for `Coin4sd.lib` after it found `Coin4d.lib`.  I would like to systematically find this out, but don't know where to start.

So my question is: what tools/commands can I use to systematically find out why my linker is also searching for `Coin4sd.lib` after it apparently first found `Coin4d.lib`?  Should I investigate the libraries that are used to build the final executable too, and check if any of those somehow refer to `Coin4sd.lib`?

Comment: As you are using `MSVC` linker you can add the `/VERBOSE` option to find out what function /translation unit is requesting the debug version of the static Coin library `Coin4sd.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I was using `COIN_DLL` as define, which apparently caused me to have the `Coin4d.*` filenames.  When I use `COIN_NOT_DLL` then if I understand things correctly, the static version of the library (which has filename `Coin4sd.*`) gets built and then my linker no longer complains.